# Julia building strings with no allocation

Tags: performance, julia, heap-memory, allocation

I am trying to build a string up from small parts to send to a websocket.

```
#Example input from somewhere else
side = "left"
jumps = 3.482
string_of_id = "Caterpillar"
sz = 100
speller = "lower"

function stringConcat(side::String, px::Float64, ticker::String, sz::Int64, ordType::String)

    return string("""{"id":\"""", string(abs(rand(Int64))), """\",\"message\":[{\"Key1\":""", string(rand(1:10000)), """,\"Leftorright\":\"""", side, 
                    """\",\"numjump\":""", string(jumps), """,\"jumpid\":\"""", string_of_id, """\",\"sz\":""", string(sz), """,\"speller\":\"""", type_of_speller,
                    """\",\"mode\":\"json\"}],"operation":"jumping\"}""")
end

# 255.780 ns (9 allocations: 911 bytes)
```

Is there a way to preallocate to avoid allocations, or other tricks I can use? Right now I believe this many allocations is quite excessive.

Comment: You may be able to use an `IOBuffer` https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.IOBuffer which lets you reuse a buffer. But you should also make sure to avoid global variables, which you seem to be using. Anyway, 911bytes seems quite low for what you are doing here.

Comment: It looks like a JSON. I would build a Dict and then use JSON3.jl to generate the JSON string.

Comment: No global variables, these are all arguments passed from somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

The https://github.com/JuliaString/Strs.jl ecosystem contains quite a few packages that attempt to improve the performance of strings in Julia, including string literals with https://github.com/JuliaString/StrLiterals.jl.

For strings that will be reused frequently, you might also check out https://github.com/JuliaString/InternedStrings.jl